# sql insert into query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Please help!

What is wrong with this INSERT INTO query?!

This is before the query on the newUser.php page

```
$result2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) AS count FROM boards");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $postNumber=$row2["count"];
}
echo $postNumber;
echo $_POST['bday'];
```

**This is the query**

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (userID, profPicLoc, age, username, realName, birthday, password, meBoardID, email) VALUES (0, 'aa', 17, '" . $_POST['username2'] . "', '" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['bday'] . "', '" . $_POST['password2'] . "', " . $postNumber+2 . ", '" . $_POST['email'] . "')";
```

The connection is made to the database correctly, the userID is auto increment, and the birthday field in the database is DATE type

it recieves the information from this form on another page...

```
<form action="newUser.php" method="post">
</br>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></input></br>
Username: @<input type="text" name="username2"></input></br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password2"></input></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"></input></br>
Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday"></br>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: *"the userID is auto increment"* - Then get rid of `userID` in your query.

Comment: don't build SQL queries with strings; it lets people hack you pretty easily.  use bound parameters.

Comment: Fred, I already tried removing the userID field, still didn't work... I think it it a small syntax error but I have no idea what is going wrong

Comment: WOOOOOOOOW I'm stupid, I forgot the parentheses before the semi colon

Comment: Yeah, you have syntax error. Missing ) at the end before semi colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` parenthesis closing is wrong. Need one more closing parenthesis at the end.
remove the `user_id` from inserting if it is AI

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (profPicLoc, age, username, realName, birthday, password, meBoardID, email) 
VALUES ('aa', 17, '" . $_POST['username2'] . "', '" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['bday'] . "', '" . $_POST['password2'] . "', " . $postNumber+2 . ", '" . $_POST['email'] . "')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it:

`mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users 
(profPicLoc, age, username, realName, birthday,     password, meBoardID, email) 
VALUES ('aa', 17, '" . $_POST['username2'] . "', '" . $_POST['name'] . "', '" . $_POST['bday'] . "', '" . $_POST['password2'] . "', " . $postNumber+2 . ", '" . $_POST['email'] . "')";`

never include primary key with auto incremented column while inserting.